# NSMenu directly open popover on icon click

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, nsmenu

When I click the logo of my app above the statusbar, I get two options: Open and close.

```
let menu = NSMenu();
menu.addItemWithTitle("open", action: "menu_open", keyEquivalent: "m")
menu.addItemWithTitle("close", action: "menu_close", keyEquivalent: "c")
```

What I want is: 
When the user clicks on the icon, I want it directly to open the NSPopover

Comment: Assuming you have a custom view as the view of the `NSStatusItem` an option is to track `mouseDown:` and call the method to show the popover.

Comment: Do you have an example? @vadian

Comment: It depends on what you have.

Comment: What is NSPopoverView?